# Can an X # of rows be generated without using stored procedures or functions?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have written the below VIEW using a UDF, but am wondering if there is a way to do this without needing a UDF. The only other option I could find is to SELECT UNION hardcoded values, but I don't like that. Any suggestions or should I just leave it as it is? I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2, so anything available there is free game.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetN(@N int)
RETURNS @numbers TABLE (N int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE (@i < @N)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @numbers SELECT @i
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
GO

CREATE VIEW Last10Weeks AS
SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())-N as WeekNumber
, DATEADD(day, (N*-7) - 1 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS StartDate 
, DATEADD(day, (N*-7) + 5 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS EndDate 
FROM GetN(10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH 
    TestData as (
        SELECT 1 as N
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N + 1 FROM TestData WHERE N < 10
    )
SELECT 
    N,
    DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())-N as WeekNumber,
    DATEADD(day, (N*-7) - 1 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(day, (N*-7) + 5 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS EndDate
FROM
    TestData
```

The "count" is specified by the "N < 10" part at the end of the second SELECT.

Prints out:

```
N   WeekNumber  StartDate   EndDate
1   39  2011-09-18 15:24:40.800 2011-09-24 15:24:40.800
2   38  2011-09-11 15:24:40.800 2011-09-17 15:24:40.800
3   37  2011-09-04 15:24:40.800 2011-09-10 15:24:40.800
4   36  2011-08-28 15:24:40.800 2011-09-03 15:24:40.800
5   35  2011-08-21 15:24:40.800 2011-08-27 15:24:40.800
6   34  2011-08-14 15:24:40.800 2011-08-20 15:24:40.800
7   33  2011-08-07 15:24:40.800 2011-08-13 15:24:40.800
8   32  2011-07-31 15:24:40.800 2011-08-06 15:24:40.800
9   31  2011-07-24 15:24:40.800 2011-07-30 15:24:40.800
10  30  2011-07-17 15:24:40.800 2011-07-23 15:24:40.800
```

Comment: @Lucero, good catch.  So it's simpler than I was thinking.  (No previous id required)

Comment: I discovered this too as I was adapting it. I needed the numbers to be like for(int i=0;i<10;i++) so I had to change it to SELECT 0 AS N and WHERE N < 9. Never heard of Recursive CTE before, this was a huge help! Thanks again!